# Генерация нескольких случайных чисел

Tags: c++, генерация-случайных-данных

Задача:
Есть динамический массив **BOMB_COLLECTION**, в нем 11 экземпляров класса **BOMB**.
Есть в переменные в классе: **Х** и **У** (координаты "бомбы"). Требуется сделать, чтобы программа сама генерировала случайные координаты Х и У.
Пишу такой код:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i <=sizeof(BOMB_COLLECTION); i++ )//всего 11 итерац.
{
    int _bombX,_bombY;
    srand(time(NULL));
     _bombX     = rand()%301;      
    srand(time(NULL));
    _bombY     = rand()%601; 
}
```

**Результат:** во всех 11 случаях  Х и У совпадают :( хотя при каждом запуске разное.

А если пишу:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i <=sizeof(BOMB_COLLECTION); i++ )//всего 11 итерац.
{
    int _bombX,_bombY;
    _bombX     = rand()%301;      
    _bombY     = rand()%601; 
}
```

**Результат:** получаем координаты первой "бомбы" (генерится нормально), координаты второй "бомбы" тоже генерится нормально, но все последующие бомбы копируют координаты **ВТОРОЙ!**

Comment: Использую Dev C++

Comment: Там где : Результат: во всех 11 случаях Х и У совпадают :( хотя пр икажлдом запуске разное. -> все координаты Х совпадают, и все координаты У совпадают, а при каждом запуске програмы эти Х и У меняются, т.е. все-таки что-то генерится

Comment: 1. Результат time() в секундах, поэтому внутри цикла одно и то же. 

2. Вы уверены, что \_bombX, \_bombY это координаты i-ой бомбы *в коллекции*, а не просто 2 независимые переменные ?

Comment: 2. я потом присваиваю _bombX, _bombY в i-ый экземпляр класса.
я для наглядности примера переделал.
1. спасибо, вылетело из головы! :)

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ @avp. Вы просто десять раз заново стартуете вычисление элементнов одной и той же последовательности.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция `srand`() инициализирует генератор случайных чисел, а фунция `rand`() - генерирует случайное число с помощью этого самого генератора. Следовательно, инициализировать генератор нужно один раз, а затем в цикле каждый раз получать новое случайное число с помощью `rand`(). См. [link text](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/)

Comment: Если я правильно понял: 
        //srand(time(NULL));
  srand(500);
  
  for (unsigned i = 0; i <=sizeof(BOMB_COLLECTION); i++ )
  {
     int _bombX,_bombY;
     _bombX     = rand()%301;      
     _bombY     = rand()%601;
        }

Но получается что и во втором случае в задаче: (скопировал)получаем координаты первой "бомбы" (генерится нормально), координаты второй "бомбы" тоже генерится нормально, но все последующие бомбы копируют координаты ВТОРОЙ!

может я чего-то недопонял(

Comment: В вашем примере переменные `_bombX` и `_bombY` локальные, дальше цикла `for()` они у вас не существуют. Занесите эти значения в BOMB_COLLECTION при каждой итерации цикла и затем посмотрите, какими значениями он заполнен.

Answer (score 1):

srand(A) генерирует последовательность псевдослучайных элементов в зависимости от ее параметра A.

rand() возвращает очередной элемент из этой последовательности.

Если A будет одинаковым при двух вызовах srand, то получим две одинаковые последовательности псевдослучайных элементов.

И нужно понимать, что rand() не генерирует, а просто возвращает уже сгенерированое ранее с помощью srand(A) число.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание насчет сущности работы rand() - так и есть.

Comment: Именно  rand() генерирует очередное псевдослучайное  число на основе предыдущего и запоминает его для следующего цикла. 

srand() устанавливает начальный элемент последовательности, но эту установку rand() не возвращает.

Comment: @avp вся псевдослучайная последовательность зависит от начального значения, и если известно первое число, то известны все последующие. По этому, rand() только выглядит как генерирующая функция, но на самом деле таковой не является.

Comment: Естественно, зависит. И именно эту установку производит srand(). Только вот, ее аргумент следующий rand() не возвращает.

Comment: возможно меня неверно поняли, фраза "возвращает уже сгенерированое ранее число" означает, не то что она возвращает число из какого то хранилища (массива), а то что все числа предопределены алгоритмом.

Comment: @avp а где я говорил что rand() возвращает аргумент функции srand() ????

Comment: srand() никакой последовательности не генерирует, а устанавливает базу, на основе которой rand() при каждом своем новом вызове генерирует очередной элемент последовательности псевдослучайных чисел. Предыдущий член хранится в статической переменной, поэтому rand(), кстати, не является реентерабельной функцией.

Comment: это пустой спор, простой пример: задаем число N = 2, все последующие числа будут на единицу больше предыдущего начиная с N. Вопрос: кто сгенерировал последовательность, тот кто задал число N или тот кто прибавляет единицу? Считайте как хотите, это риторический вопрос.

Comment: > И нужно понимать, что rand() не генерирует, а просто возвращает уже сгенерированое ранее с помощью srand(A) число.

Извините, но это неверно. Функция rand() именно генерирует очередное значение псевдослучайной последовательности. Да, она полностью детерминирована зерном. Но есть соответствующая область математики и устоявшаяся терминология, в которой под генерацией понимается вычисление очередного значения на основе некоторой (обычно рекуррентной) формулы. Смотрите китов: Джорджа Марсалью, например.